# Iterate through multiple array and execute function

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [animal] => dog
            [color] => black
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [animal] => cat
            [color] => white
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [animal] => mouse
            [color] => grey
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [nickname] => snuggles
                    [nickname] => buddy
                )

        )

)
```

I now need to execute a function on every value in the attribute array. So for example capitalize `SNUGGLES` and `BUDDY`.

This is my approach:

```
$array = array(
    array("animal"=>"dog","color"=>"black"),
     array("animal"=>"cat","color"=>"white"),
     array("animal"=>"mouse","color"=>"grey", "attributes" => array("nicknames" => "snuggles", "nicknames" => "buddy"))
);

foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    foreach ( $value as $key1 => $value1 ) {
        if ($key1 == 'attributes') {
            foreach ( $value as $key2 => $value2 ) {
                $value2 =  strtoupper($value2);
                $array [$key] [$key1] [$key2]= $key2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

> strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ...

Comment: You can't be testing with the same data as you've posted in your question. Since the there isn't any key called `dropdown` in the array you've posted, this `$key1 == 'dropdown'` would never evaluate as true and `strtoupper()` would never be executed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: My bad, just a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong variable in your inner loop:

```
foreach ( $value as $key2 => $value2 ) {
          ^^^^^^ here
    ...
}
```

Judging by the code, you would want to use `$value1` there:

```
foreach ( $value1 as $key2 => $value2 ) {
          ^^^^^^^ here
    ...
}
```

Assuming that `dropdown` => `attributes`...

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this is..

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    /* check whether the index is available or not */
    if( isset( $value['attributes'] ) ) {
         foreach ( $value['attributes'] as $namekey => $names ) {
             /* here capitalise the value and save in same index */
             $array[$key]['attributes'][$namekey] = strtoupper($names);
         }
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

OUTPUT's:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [animal] => dog [color] => black )
        [1] => Array ( [animal] => cat [color] => white )
        [2] => Array ( [animal] => mouse [color] => grey [attributes] => Array ( [nicknames] => BUDDY ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

You can do it like this:

Let the inputs be (same as yours):

```
$array = array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "animal" => "dog"
    "color" => "black"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "animal" => "cat"
    "color" => "white"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "animal" => "mouse"
    "color" => "grey"
    "attributes" => array:1 [
      "nicknames" => "snuggles"
      "nicknames" => "buddy"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Then you can manipulate through your array in a more simplest & shortest way like this:

```
function toUpper($val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        return array_map('toUpper', $val);
    }
    return strtoupper($val);
}

$final_arr = array_map('toUpper', $array);
print_r($final_arr);
```

This will give you the output as according to your inputs:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "animal" => "DOG"
    "color" => "BLACK"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "animal" => "CAT"
    "color" => "WHITE"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "animal" => "MOUSE"
    "color" => "GREY"
    "attributes" => array:1 [
      "nicknames" => "BUDDY"
    ]
  ]
]
```

> Your provided inputs have an array key named `attributes` which contains a array having 2 values of same key-value pair `nicknames`. In that case this will take the last one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very nice, but modification is needed. Just 'attributtes' sub-array should be modified...

Comment: @sinisake - Yup, just `attributes` is needed to be modified. Kindly upvote! :D

Comment: "I now need to execute a function on every value in the attribute array. So for example capitalize SNUGGLES and BUDDY." - so, not every element, just one part of array. :)

Comment: I didn't get you, can you please post a new question for your problem as questions are not meant to be asked here!

Comment: I didn't posted question, just tried to explain what is wrong: OP doesn't need ALL VALUES of array uppercased, just some of them. :)  So, maybe array_map isn't suitable for this.

Answer (score 0):

//Code : To capitalize each value. You can use below :

```
$array = array(
    array("animal"=>"dog","color"=>"black"),
     array("animal"=>"cat","color"=>"white"),
     array("animal"=>"mouse","color"=>"grey", "attributes" => array("nickname1" => "snuggles", "nickname2" => "buddy"))
);

foreach ( $array as $index => $value ) 
{
    foreach ( $value as $key1 => $value1 )
    {
        if(is_array($value1))
        {
            foreach ( $value1 as $key2 => $value2 )
            {
                if(is_array($value2))
                {
                    foreach ( $value2 as $key3 => $value3 )
                    {
                        $array[$index][$key1][$key2][$key3] = strtoupper($value3);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $array[$index][$key1][$key2] = strtoupper($value2);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $array[$index][$key1] = strtoupper($value1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [animal] => DOG
            [color] => BLACK
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [animal] => CAT
            [color] => WHITE
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [animal] => MOUSE
            [color] => GREY
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [nickname1] => SNUGGLES
                    [nickname2] => BUDDY
                )

        )

)
```