# How to get every key-value-pair from PHP-array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to get every key-value-pair from an array in PHP. The structure is different and not plannable, for example it is possible that a key contains an additional array and so on (multidimensional array?). The function I would like to call has the task to replace a specific string from the value. The problem is that the function `foreach`, `each`, ... only use the main keys and values.

Is there existing a function that has the `foreach`-function with **every** key/value?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php - it will not cover all cases (more complicaed structures?)...but, should help - basically, you need recursion -> check if value is array, call function again, etc, etc... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088687/recursive-loop-for-multidimenional-arrays

Comment: @sinisake Is it possible to retrieve the full var-"path"/parent key, for example when my code is `$fruits = ['sweet' => ["hi" => "nett"], 'sour' => 'lemon']; function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "$key holds $item\n";
}

array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'test_print');` That I get as additional path which key is meant? $fruits["sweet"]["hi"]

Comment: Yesterday someone had similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284689/iterate-through-multiple-array-and-execute-function/41284991#41284991 please check latest answer, it should help.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach to this kind of task is using a **recursive funcion**.

Let's go step by step:

First you need the `foreach` control statement...

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

..that let you parse the associative array without knowing keys' names beforehand.

Then `is_array` and `is_string` (and eventually `is_object`, `is_integer`...) let you check the type of each value so you can act properly.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php

**If you find the string to be operated then you do the replace task**

If you find an array the function recalls itself passing the array just parsed.

**This way the original array will be parsed down to the deepest level without missing and key-value pair.**

---

**Example:**

```
function findAndReplaceStringInArray( $theArray )
{
    foreach ( $theArray as $key => $value)
    {
        if( is_string( $theArray[ $key ] )
        {
            // the value is a string
            // do your job...

            // Example:
            // Replace 'John' with 'Mike' if the `key` is 'name'

            if( $key == 'name' && $theArray[ $key ] == "John" )
            {
                $theArray[ $key ] = "Mike";
            }
        }
        else if( is_array( $theArray[ $key ] )
        {
            // treat the value as a nested array

            $nestedArray = $theArray[ $key ];

            findAndReplaceStringInArray( $nestedArray );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not a built in function that works as you expect but you can adapt it using the [RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php), walking recursively the multidimensional array, and with the flag `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST`, you would get all the elements of the same level first, before going deeper, not missing any pair.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $key => $item) {
    // LOGIC
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a recursive function to treat it.

```
function sweep_array(array $array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value){

        if(is_array($value))
        {
            sweep_array($value);
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";
        }   
    }
}
```